Postgresql cache lookup failed for attribute
Probably about once a week I get an error on one of my databases that says
 ERROR: cache lookup failed for attribute 1 of relation 144348

I've done a fair amount of Googling, and I really can't find anything that seems to match.
I'm using PostgreSQL 14.
My questions: What might be causing this? and how to fix it.
Please let me know if you require additional information.

What is the result from this query: SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 144348; ? And can you make a backup? Or does that fail?

Also, what do you get for SELECT attname, atttypid, attlen, attnum, atttypmod FROM pg_attribute WHERE attrelid = 144348 AND attnum > 0 ORDER BY attnum;.

Do you use a virtual machine and, if yes, what is the hypervisor and how is it managed ?
